# Get one character to the left on the keyboard programmatically

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

In a keyboard, if I have an ASCII code for character 'v' (small caps), then how should I get the ASCII value for the character one left to it in java? That is, for instance I have ASCII value of 'v' which is 118, now as per the standard qwerty keyboard the character left of 'v' is 'c'. How to achieve this in Java? Any idea?

Assume 'm' is to the left of 'z' and it's always small caps.

Assume I have a function like this:

```
String oneLeft(String s) { }
```

I want to come to the conclusion of displaying the character one left to the character passed keeping QWERTY keypad in mind.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: What's the character one left of `z`, `a` and `q`?

Comment: Create some arrays: qwertyuiop asdfghjkl zxcvbnm

Comment: Create a map and use that as a reference!

Comment: @AndyTurner - The one left of 'z' is 'm' and it is always small caps.

Comment: You cannot do this in any language, it is very keyboard layout and locale (language) specific. E.g. in German keyboard (QWERTZ) the Z is next to T where as in English layout (QWERTY) Y following T.

Comment: @VladimirL. Assuming it is QWERTY layout we should arrive at a logic.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I will be giving this a try.

Comment: @JoeC Just like that. New to the algorithmic world. I wanna improve. ;-)

Comment: There are several ways to do it, depending on how you use the java application. Is it terminal based application? is it graphical? if graphical, then which tool kit do you use: awt, swing, fx, ..? Is it web-based application? You need to ask a right question.

Comment: @Serge It is a terminal based application. Assuming an input I have to arrive at the output.

Comment: Assume I have a function like this:
    String oneLeft(String s) {

    }
I want to come to the conclusion of displaying the character one left to the character passed keeping QWERTY keypad in mind.

Comment: I have edited my question. It's only for QWERTY keypad.

Comment: You might want to mention in your question the fact that you want to wrap around to include only alphabetical characters.

Comment: AFAIK, Java does not know about the layout of any keyboard.

Comment: So, you are not talking about physically typing a key and figuring out what you typed. Because in this case you have also take in account all language settings and key re-mappers in a host OS which can create soft layouts and produce unicode or whatever. Also there is a variety of hw keyboards with different numbers of keys, 101, 102. 106, .. and different allocation of those. Otherwise you have to stick to a particular model of the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with simply using a String as the definition for the `keyboard`:

```
public static char oneLeft (char s)
{
    // note the wrap-around chars ('p', 'l', 'm')
    final String keyboard = "pqwertyuioplasdfghjklmzxcvbnm"; 

    // use lastIndexOf to not conflict with wrap-around chars
    int index = keyboard.lastIndexOf(s); 

    return (index > 0) ? keyboard.charAt(index - 1) : s;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
System.out.println(oneLeft('v')); // prints c
System.out.println(oneLeft('z')); // prints m
System.out.println(oneLeft('9')); // prints 9

System.out.println(oneLeft('P')); // prints P
```

Comment: some explanation about the wrap-around chars would be pretty helpful. However, this is excellent solution! Also, will this work if I pass in string of characters like "bbb" in which case it should print "vvv".

Comment: I am getting a "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at _runldqiu.oneLeft(file.java on line 4)

Comment: "Also, will this work if I pass in string of characters like "bbb" in which case it should print "vvv"?" - This code works only for one character, but can certainly be adapted to handle a String.

Comment: I am sorry for the last comment. I am getting this below error when I pass "bbb" as input:

error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
    return (index > 0) ? keyboard.charAt(index - 1) : s;
                                        ^
    char cannot be converted to String
1 error

Comment: oh ok. I guess that's the reason for the above error. I am trying to pass "bbb" as input.

Comment: I wanted the program to work for single character as well as for group of characters,

Comment: I changed the last return statement to "return (index > 0) ? keyboard.charAt(index - 1) + "" : s;" and it worked for a single character input.

Answer (score 2):

For really fast lookups (which you don't need, but for the sake of learning something fun), you could create a character array whose offsets are the characters you want to lookup.  ASCII lower-case characters fall in the range of 97 through 122, so a new char[123] (or new char['z'+1]) will fit all your letters plus some unused space.

So, you want to create an array, such that cCrypt=f[cPlain];

Spam your finger across the keyboard to create the three strings for each row which, you've indicated, each individually wrap around (e.g. 'm' is left of 'z'):

```
public class DickTracyRing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] encoder=new char['z'+1];
        fill(encoder, "qwertyuiop");
        fill(encoder, "asdfghjkl");
        fill(encoder, "zxcvbnm");
        System.out.println(encode("my message", encoder));
    }

    private static String encode(String str, char[] lookup) {
        char[] text=str.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            if (text[i]>='a' && text[i]<='z') text[i]=lookup[text[i]];
        }
        return new String(text);
    }

    private static void fill(char[] lookup, String row) {
        char[] crow = row.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < crow.length; i++) {
            lookup[crow[i]] = crow[(crow.length-1+i)%crow.length];
        }
    }
}
```

The output of encode("my message", encoder) is `nt nwaaldw`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the JDK, but the simplest is a map:

```
private static final Map<Character, Character> LEFT_KEYS = new HashMap<Character, Character>() {{
    put('v', 'c');
    put('w', 'q');
    // etc for all keys that have keys to the left
}};
```

Then in code:

```
char key; // read from wherever
Character left = LEFT_KEYS.get(key); // could be null
```